# Slerp interpolation of angle results in -nan(ind)

Tags: c++, math, interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate a 2D angle and it works 99.9% of the time. For some reason I'm getting -nan(ind) for some values, like:

```
lastAngle = -0.0613451
currentAngle = -0.061421
alpha = 0.218813
```

This is the code:

```
inline float slerpRotation(const float& angle1, const float& angle2, const float& alpha)
{
    auto v1 = b2Vec2{std::cos(angle1), std::sin(angle1)};
    auto v2 = b2Vec2{std::cos(angle2), std::sin(angle2)};
    auto v = this->slerp(v1, v2, alpha);
    return std::atan2(v.y, v.x);
}

inline b2Vec2 slerp(const b2Vec2& v1, const b2Vec2& v2, const float& alpha)
{
    auto cosAngle = v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y;
    auto angle = std::acos(cosAngle);
    auto angleAlpha = angle * alpha;
    auto v3 = (v2 - (cosAngle * v1)).Normalize();
    auto x = v1.x * std::cos(angleAlpha) + v3 * std::sin(angleAlpha);
    auto y = v1.y * std::cos(angleAlpha) + v3 * std::sin(angleAlpha);
    return b2Vec2{x, y};
}
```

All this examples results in inf num:

```
slerpRotation(-0.0613451f, -0.061421f, 0.218813f);
slerpRotation(-1.63139f, -1.63139f, 0.723703f);
slerpRotation(-0.0614404f, -0.0614034f, 0.199831f);
slerpRotation(0.0194162f, 0.0194164f, 0.259074f);
```

I've tried to solve this problem for a while now without knowing what causes this problem, do you guys happened to know how to solve this?

Comment: What does `b2Vec2::Normalize` do with a {0,0} vector?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm it returns 0

Comment: heh, this line seems to be the problem: auto angle = std::acos(cosAngle); Getting a nan value back

Comment: Problem was that cosAngle seemed to be 1 all the time, even when i printed it to the console but when checking if it was greater than 1.0f it returned true which made acos return a nan. So to solve the problem I have to set it to 1.0f if its greater and -1.0f if its less.

Comment: In the last two computation lines, surely you want to use the coordinates of `v3`, not the full vector that results in sums of scalars and vectors. Or combine them into one vector combination `return cos(angleAlpha)*v1+sin(angleAlpha)*v3;`.

Comment: @LutzL Well I have to do it like that or I'll get a invalid operands to binary expression for b2vec2 and float. Do you mean the result would be different by doing that?

Comment: I can not understand how it works in the present form. `v1.x * std::cos(angleAlpha)` is a scalar, `v3 * std::sin(angleAlpha)` is or should be a vector, there should be no sensible way to add these terms. If that compiles, then it is a serious error in the `b2vec2` methods.

Comment: And no, this should be no source for a NaN result. The prime suspect is that the argument of acos is larger than 1.

Comment: @LutzL well I've changed the name of v3 to norm since it is not a vector. V3 in this case is just a float value, does that clear things up?

Comment: No, it helps not. `v1-cosAngle*v2` is a vector, `Normalize()` should return a vector of norm 1 in the same direction. With `v3` as scalar, the last 2 formulas make no sense geometrically.

Comment: @LutzL according to box2d, normalize does the following: 

Convert this vector into a unit vector. Returns the length.

Comment: Then the code should be, to have geometrical meaning, `v3=v1-cosAngle*v2; v3.Normalize(); return std::cos(angleAlpha)*v1+std::sin(angleAlpha)*v3;`. But even then, there are more ways to de-singularize the code, compute `v3` as the 90° rotation of `v1` and use the `atan2` function for angle computations, reduce everything to angle manipulations, ... find that you are just doing linear interpolation of the angles.

Comment: I've added what I mean as a complete method to my answer, please try on your regular test cases that it does what you expect it to do and then that it also works on the singular test cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end you are computing

```
angle1+alpha*(angle2-angle1)
```

or if you want to exclude some fringe cases,

```
angle1+alpha*reduce2pi(angle2-angle1)
```

where

```
 reduce2pi(phi) = fmod( 3*pi + fmod(phi, 2*pi), 2*pi)-pi
```

Note that these formulas are completely singularity free, as there is no division. It is not necessary to switch forth and back between angles and their point on the unit circle.

In code, that would be

```
inline float slerpRotation(const float& angle1, const float& angle2, const float& alpha)
{
    auto angleDiff = angle2-angle1;
    angleDiff = std::fmod(angleDiff, 2*std::M_PI);
    angleDiff = std::fmod(angleDiff + 3*std::M_PI, 2*std::M_PI)-std::M_PI;
    return angle1+alpha*angleDiff;
}
```

---

*(12/13/2016) combining several comments:* If you insist on using exactly this interface structure, then you can get a singularity free method as follows:

```
inline b2Vec2 slerp(const b2Vec2& v1, const b2Vec2& v2, const float& alpha)
{
    auto angle = std::atan2(v1.x*v2.y - v1.y*v2.x, v1.x*v2.x + v1.y*v2.y);
    auto angleAlpha = angle * alpha;
    auto v3=b2Vec2{-v1.y, v1.x}; // rotation by 90°
    return std::cos(angleAlpha)*v1 + std::sin(angleAlpha)*v3;
}
```

Comment: sorry but I don't get that. Which part did i get wrong?

Comment: You are doing a lot of complicated geometry computation to get the result of a simple linear interpolation of the angles. For the actual error first check that `cosAlpha` is never larger than `1.0`. Or use the `atan2` function to get the angle from `cosAlpha` and `sinAlpha=v1.x*v2.y-v1.y*v2.x`.

Comment: thanks for the update mate. It looks like this one is working exactly as my example with less code. When you say insist on using this interface, do you have a better solution on how to interpolate the angle?

Comment: Yes, my second formula should give exactly the same result.

Comment: damn, this was really good mate, thanks alot. Perhaps I should post my hermite interpolation so you could take a look at it and perhaps optimize that one as well :)